# Problema con CakePHP Excel

Tags: php, excel, cakephp

Como dice el título estoy intentando implementar CakePHP Excel, y con los 3 plugins probados hasta el momento:

- Cewi Excel
- dakota/CakeExcel
- maraya/CakePHPExcel

Después de instalarlos con Composer, y realizar toda la configuración, al momento de insertar este código (necesario) en el Appcontroler.php

```
public function initialize()
    {
            parent::initialize();
            $this->loadComponent('RequestHandler', [
                    'viewClassMap' => ['xlsx' => 'Cewi/Excel.Excel']
    ]);
        }
```

Me salta el error var_export does not handle circular references.

Estuve investigando sobre el tema, pero no hay información clara al parecer sobre ese error en CakePHP.
Se agradecen las respuestas desde ya.

Answer (score 0):

Al final solucioné el problema.

En el archivo ObjectRegistry.php

Hay que cambiar reemplazar las líneas 142 y 143 var_export por print_r